# WCF Full Duplex Application with Websocket Client

Tags: javascript, web-services, wcf, websocket

We had created WCF web service with one method. Service is hosted on external server i.e. Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.0.

WCF Service URL: http://184.106.9.214/WCFReportingService/Service1.svc

WCF method:

```
 public void ProcessReport()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            // some logic to process the report
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            // Get the callback channel to send messages to the client
            OperationContext.Current.
                GetCallbackChannel<IReportServiceCallback>().Progress(i);
        }
    }
```

We are trying to create client using HTML5 and JavaScript. Below is the logic we used to initiate the connection.

```
 ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/WCFReportService/Service1.svc");
            alert(ws);

            ws.onopen = function () {

                // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                ws.send("Message to send");
                alert("Message is sent...");

                $("#spanStatus").text("connected");
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                alert("Message is received...");

                $("#spanStatus").text(evt.data);
            };
            ws.onerror = function (evt) {
                $("#spanStatus").text(evt.message);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                // websocket is closed.
                alert("Connection is closed...");

                $("#spanStatus").text("disconnected");
            };
```

We were not able to establish the connection to server. We are thinking that it might be something to do with client side web.config file. But we are not sure how to implement or build connection.

Can anyone help us to build client-server connection?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question in it's current form is not really answerable. You will need to include more detail, like what errors you are getting when calling the service, and what the client code looks like. Please also read the stackoverflow guidance on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone with similar problem I had. Below are the links I used and I was able to get it working.

Introduction 2 : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-2 
Introduction 3 : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619343/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-3